# Spark Unit Testing: How to initialize sc only once for all the Suites using FunSuite

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, scalatest

I want to write spark unit test cases and I am using FunSuite for it. 
But i want that my sparkContext is initialized only once , used by all the Suites and then is killed when all Suites completes.

```
abstract class baseClass extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter{
  before {
    println("initialize spark context")
  }
  after {
    println("kill spark context")
  }

}



@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class A extends baseClass{
test("for class A"){
//assert
}

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class B extends baseClass{
test(for class b){
//assert
}
}
```

but when i run sbt test 
I can see println statement baseClass has been called from both the tests. Obsiously When the object is created for both the classes A and B , Abstract
baseclass is called.
But then how can we achieve my purpose i.e spark context is iniliazed only once while all the test cases are run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to share the context between *suites* - you'll have to make it static. Then you can use a `lazy` value to make it start on first use. As for shutting it down - you can leave it to the automatic Shutdown hook created each time a context is created.

It would look something like:

```
abstract class SparkSuiteBase extends FunSuite {
    lazy val sparkContext = SparkSuiteBase.sparkContext
}

// putting the Spark Context inside an object allows reusing it between tests
object SparkSuiteBase {
    private lazy val sparkContext = ??? // create the context here
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. Deviating from original question. Is there any way I can add these two classes A and B into a single Suite ??

Comment: A class that extends FunSuite _is_ a suite.. So i can't see how. You can create many tests testing many classes in one suite class - not sure what distinction you're trying to achieve by separating A and B.

Comment: I wanted to test different src classes in different test classes. So was thinking to create two different test classes A and B

Comment: That makes sense, but then - why insist on single suite? Anyway, that's indeed off topic, please indicate whether your original question was answered or not.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend using the `spark-testing-base` library in order to manage the lifecycle of a sparkContext or sparkSession during your tests.
You won't have to pollute your tests by overriding the `beforeAll`, `afterAll` methods and managing the lifecycle of the `sparkSession`/`sparkContext`.

You can share one `sparkSession`/`sparkContext` for all the tests by overriding the following method : 
`def reuseContextIfPossible: Boolean = true`

for more details : https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/wiki/SharedSparkContext

I hope it helps!

Comment: Note: using spark-testing-base will at some point make you to use hive, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: Use the excellent https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base library that does exactly that (and provides many other nice treats). After following the readme, it's as simle as mixing-in `SharedSparkContext` instead of your `baseClass`, and you'll have an `sc: SparkContext` value ready to use in your test

**Option 2**: to do it yourself, you'd want to mix-in `BeforeAndAfterAll` and not `BeforeAndAfter`, and implement `beforeAll` and `afterAll`, which is exactly what the above-mentioned `SharedSparkContext` does.

Comment: I already provided similar answer and removed. Based on the comments ("_dont think this is working, it shows same result . print statement is being called from both the test classes_") I believe that OP wants the same context for all suites.

Comment: Yes. After using Option2: sbt test prints the statements twice.
initialize spark context
initialize spark context
kill spark context
kill spark context

Comment: Yes ..I believe two classes in my project create two different suites. So My requirement is to share sc between different suites. Have edited my question accordinly